# Add an area field using a shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, fields-attributes

I have an attribute table of xy points that I have plotted on a map, and a shapefile that divides the map into 46 different areas.

I want to add a field/variable to the table containing the xy points, that states which area of the map the point is located.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create an [XY event layer in ArcMap](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00s50000001z000000) (when you "plot" your XY values). After that, you can export your event layer to a feature class inside a geodatabase (recommended) or as a shapefile. You can now run the [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/finding_what_s_inside_a_polygon/005s00000034000000/) operation to find out inside what polygons each of the plotted points located. The same can be achieved by using the [Spatial Join geoprocessing tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/Spatial_Join/00080000000q000000/) instead of the manipulating the layers inside the table of contents.